# Matrix horizontal alignment

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I am trying to use the [Gauss](http://www.tex.ac.uk/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/gauss/gauss-doc.pdf) TeX package to display matrices. I have two problems with the following code (not so important):

```
    \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{gauss}     
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\begin{gmatrix}[b]
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{4}{5} & \text{\small{-}}\frac{3}{5} & \frac{2}{5} & \text{\small{-}}\frac{1}{5} \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \text{\small{-}}\frac{3}{5} & \frac{6}{5} & \text{\small{-}}\frac{4}{5} & \frac{2}{5} \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{3}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \text{\small{-}}\frac{1}{2} & \frac{3}{4} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \text{\small{-}}\frac{1}{5} & \frac{2}{5} & \text{\small{-}}\frac{3}{5} & \frac{4}{5}
\rowops
\add[\cdot ({-}\frac{3}{4})]{3}{2}
\end{gmatrix} \cong
\begin{gmatrix}[b]
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{4}{5} & \text{\small{-}}\frac{3}{5} & \frac{2}{5} & \text{\small{-}}\frac{1}{5} \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \text{\small{-}}\frac{3}{5} & \frac{6}{5} & \text{\small{-}}\frac{4}{5} & \frac{2}{5} \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{2}{5} & \text{\small{-}}\frac{4}{5} & \frac{6}{5} & \text{\small{-}}\frac{3}{5} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \text{\small{-}}\frac{1}{5} & \frac{2}{5} & \text{\small{-}}\frac{3}{5} & \frac{4}{5}
\end{gmatrix}\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

I bypassed the alignment a bit by using `\text{\small{-}}` in stead of `-`, to make the fractions appear under each other, but they still don't line up quite nicely and the matrix need more vertical space but I cannot seem to figure out how to do this. Any help would be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gauss` package seems to impede easy answers. Here's a solutions that isn't great but works: Replace all your `\text{\small{-}}` with `\llap{-}` (this will yield the alignment you desire), and add a strut to each row:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{gauss}
\newcommand\mystrut{\rule{0pt}{2.5ex}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\begin{gmatrix}[b]
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{4}{5} & \llap{-}\frac{3}{5} & \frac{2}{5} & \llap{-}\frac{1}{5} \mystrut \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \llap{-}\frac{3}{5} & \frac{6}{5} & \llap{-}\frac{4}{5} & \frac{2}{5} \mystrut \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{3}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \llap{-}\frac{1}{2} & \frac{3}{4} & 0 \mystrut \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \llap{-}\frac{1}{5} & \frac{2}{5} & \llap{-}\frac{3}{5} & \frac{4}{5} \mystrut
\rowops
\add[\cdot ({-}\frac{3}{4})]{3}{2}
\end{gmatrix} \cong
\begin{gmatrix}[b]
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{4}{5} & \llap{-}\frac{3}{5} & \frac{2}{5} & \llap{-}\frac{1}{5} \mystrut \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \llap{-}\frac{3}{5} & \frac{6}{5} & \llap{-}\frac{4}{5} & \frac{2}{5} \mystrut \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{2}{5} & \llap{-}\frac{4}{5} & \frac{6}{5} & \llap{-}\frac{3}{5} \mystrut \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \llap{-}\frac{1}{5} & \frac{2}{5} & \llap{-}\frac{3}{5} & \frac{4}{5} \mystrut 
\end{gmatrix}\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

(The builtin `\strut` is a bit too small, so I defined a larger `\mystrut`.)

Comment: @user1912: You might want to check back; it could happen that tomorrow someone has a better answer.

Comment: Yea I will surely do that, however, your answer perfectly does the job and all looks fine. I don't care if the underlying code is a bit "hacky" as noone but me sees it

Answer (score 0):

One way to get more vertical space is to use `\extrarowheight`, in the `array` package. The syntax is `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{x}`, where `x` is a measure (e.g., 2pt, 3pt, etc). The effect only occurs if its value plus `\baselineskip`x`\arraystretch` is larger than the actual height of the cell. I usually add two or three points, and that makes the fractions come out suitably separated.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work with the gauss package which I need to display the steps I am doing.

Comment: @user1912: fair enough.